# Javascript Prototypes Assignments

Tags: javascript

In javascript , when you assign one object to another you in fact create a reference or an alias , two names pointing to the same thing . At least that's the way it is in this case:

```
var obja = { val : 0 };
var objb = obja;
objb.val =20;
obja  //Object {val: 20}
```

However , in prototypical inheritance, that (the object assignment) is one of the ways we're supposed to create inheritance . Taken from Object Oriented Javascript (Stoyan Stefanov) :

```
function Shape(){}
// augment prototype
Shape.prototype.name = 'shape';
Shape.prototype.toString = function() {return this.name;};
function TwoDShape(){}
// take care of inheritance
TwoDShape.prototype = Shape.prototype;
TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;
// augment prototype
TwoDShape.prototype.name = '2D shape';
function Triangle(side, height) {
this.side = side;
this.height = height;
}
// take care of inheritance
Triangle.prototype = TwoDShape.prototype;
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;
Triangle.prototype.name = 'Triangle';
```

The question is - why do these assignments work they way they do ? If I look at the obja and objb assignment from earlier , I would expect that this :

```
TwoDShape.prototype = Shape.prototype;
```

Would cause TwoDShape and Shape to have the same exact prototype (both reference the same thing) . Then when TwoDShape starts adding properties to his prototype I would expect them to be added to Shape , while this obviously isn't happening .

Comment: Shape.prototype.name == '2D shape' before the last line, how are they not adding?

Comment: `TwoDShape.prototype = Shape.prototype;` This was actually in the book? *You* are correct. It causes them to have the same prototype object, so whatever you add to `TwoDShape.prototype` is also added to `Shape.prototype`, which means objects created from the `Shape` constructor are going to inherit the `TwoDShape` stuff. Not good.

Comment: Yes , from the book . very confusing ..need to re-read everything maybe I missed something .

Comment: @Givi Can you give an example please?

Comment: Either the book is wrong, or that's an example of what *not* to do.

Comment: @Joel_Blum: Basically you want to assign to `TwoDShape.prototype` a new object that *inherits* from `Shape.prototype`. That way objects you create from `TwoDShape` will inherit whatever you put on that object, as well as the items that object is inheriting *(from `Shape.prototype`)*, and because it's a new unique object, it doesn't affect `Shape.prototype` itself in any way. I won't bother showing you the common "legacy" way of doing it. What you should do is `TwoDShape.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);`. This creates a new object that inherits from the `Shape.prototype` object.

Comment: ...This also shows another interesting fact. You don't need a constructor function at all to set up inheritance. For example, you can do `var myobj = Object.create(TwoDShape.prototype);`, and now you've got a new object that has `TwoDShape.prototype` in its prototype chain. And to separate it away from the constructors even further, you can do it with any native object. `var mysuper = {foo:"bar"}; var mysub = Object.create(mysuper);` There you go. The `mysub` object is a new object that inherits from the `mysuper` object. You can create as many as you want that inherit from `mysuper`.